# Apply HTML Tag Conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The following is the code I have for displaying a set of attendees in an event:

```
<div ng-repeat="attendee in individualEvent.attendees" ng-if="findUser(attendee)>
    <a href="/#/users/{{attendee}}">{{attendee}}</a></td>
</div>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
$scope.findUser = function(attendee){
  if(attendee === $scope.currentUser.username){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
};
```

This does not work unfortunately. Rather, it simply makes everything displayed go away.
I am not sure how I can apply this HTML tag conditionally. If the attendee's name is equal to `$scope.currentUser.username`, I don't want the `<a href>` to be applied to it. Any ideas on how to do so? Thanks!

EDIT: I just want it so that the all the names in the attendees array appears but the  tag is not applied to that in which the attendee is equivalent to the currentUser.username (i.e. the attendee name is simply text, not hyperlinked).

EDIT 2: I added in ng-switch but I have no idea why it's not working. Might it be a scoping issue?

```
<div ng-repeat="attendee in individualEvent.attendees" ng-switch on="individualEvent.attendees">
    <div ng-switch-when="currentUser.username">{{attendee}}</div>
    <div ng-switch-default><a href="/#/users/{{attendee}}">{{attendee}}</a></div>
</div>
```

I double checked that my attendee and current.username are not null or empty, and that one of the attendee values is equal to the currentUser.username value. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: can't you use `ng-show` to show/hide?

Comment: Did you try adding the `ng-if` directive on the `<a>` tag?

Comment: @Mritunjay I just want it so that the name shows up but no <a href> tag is applied to it (it is just text)

Comment: @UmurKontacı Thank you for pointing me to this question. I have tried to adopt the changes based on what I have seen from your answers but I still cannot get this to work properly. I edited the code above, do you mind looking and seeing why it does not work?

Comment: @user1567909 You are setting ng-switch on to the array `individualEvent.attendees` but comparing it with the current user name. Comparing arrays to strings will return false most of the time. Do: `ng-switch on="attendee"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter instead of `ng-if`. A filter is executed on each item in the input list, and the item is selected only if the filter matches. So:

```
<div ng-repeat="attendee in individualEvent.attendees | filter:findUser">
    <a href="/#/users/{{attendee}}">{{attendee}}</a></td>
</div>
```

The scope function `findUser` is called with `attendee` as the input parameter.

Comment: Sorry if I was being confusing but I wanted a way so that all the people in individualEvent.attendees to display, but that the attendee that has the same name as the currentUser.username would not be hyperlinked--I still want to show him but I would like his username to show up as not hyperlinked. Any ideas on how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="attendee in individualEvent.attendees" ng-if="findUser(attendee)>
<a href="/#/users/{{attendee}}" ng-if="!isCurrentUser(attendee)">{{attendee}}</a>
</div>

$scope.isCurrentUser = function(attendee){
  return $scope.currentUser.username === attendee
}
```

This should work, but I also like the filter approach by metacubed.

*edit after your comment

This example should work.

```
<div ng-repeat="attendee in individualEvent.attendees" ng-if="findUser(attendee)>
   <a href="/#/users/{{attendee}}" ng-if="!isCurrentUser(attendee)">{{attendee}}</a>
   <div ng-if="isCurrentUser(attendee)">{{attendee}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if I was being confusing but I wanted a way so that all the people in individualEvent.attendees to display, but that the attendee that has the same name as the currentUser.username would not be hyperlinked--I still want to show him but I would like his username to show up as not hyperlinked. Any ideas on how to do so?